# CakePHP generates SQL statement with error for two linked tables. Not Unique Alias

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables linked by a foreign key - college_id
The code for it was all generated using the cake bake feature.

Whenever I try to call the view generated by CakePHP for one of the tables it always generates a SQL statement with error.

The error is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Courses'

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT Courses.course_id AS `Courses__course_id`, Courses.course_name AS `Courses__course_name`, Courses.cource_code AS `Courses__cource_code`, Courses.college_id AS `Courses__college_id`, Colleges.college_id AS `Colleges__college_id`, Colleges.college_name AS `Colleges__college_name`
FROM courses Courses
    INNER JOIN courses Courses ON Courses.course_id = (Courses.course_id)
    INNER JOIN colleges Colleges ON Colleges.college_id = (Courses.college_id)
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I know that the error is in the fact that is using twice the alias "Courses" in the same query. 
Here: "FROM courses Courses INNER JOIN courses Courses"

But I can't find a way to prevent this from happening.
I looked into the Linking tables docs for cakephp 3.0 but I couldn't find a way where I could define the way it names this alias.
Any hints?

CoursesTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\Course;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Courses Model
 *
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Courses
 * @property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Colleges
 */
class CoursesTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('courses');
        $this->displayField('course_name');
        $this->primaryKey('course_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Courses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Colleges', [
            'foreignKey' => 'college_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->requirePresence('course_name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('course_name')
            ->add('course_name', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('cource_code', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('cource_code');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['course_id'], 'Courses'));
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['college_id'], 'Colleges'));
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Course Table Schema:

```
course_id - PK
course_name
course_dode
college_id - FK
```

Comment: Why are you joining `courses`, at all? You're not doing anything with the joined data. Just join `courses` to `colleges`; no need to join `courses` to `courses` and then to `colleges`.

Comment: I see what you mean it is indeed not needed.
The code was automatically generated by cake so it got messed up somehow.
I did look into the table definition but all looks fine.

`        $this->table('courses');
        $this->displayField('course_name');
        $this->primaryKey('course_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Colleges', [
            'foreignKey' => 'college_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Courses', [
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);`

Comment: Are you intending to have a courses belong to courses relationship? It looks like you've incorrectly setup this association.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja not at all, courses should belong to colleges and that is the only association needed.
Thing is cakephp seems to have done  this association automatically and I can't figure out where it is defined to fix it.

Comment: Is there a `course_id` column on your `courses` table that would cause Cake bake to create an association? Presumably there is a `belongsTo` relationship in your `CoursesTable` which Cake has created that you need to remove to fix the problem.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja yes it has, added schema and Course Table definition above.
I did tried to remove the belongsTo in the CoursesTable but when I do that it changes to giving a code error saying that "Courses is not associated with Courses".
I reverted it back as I noticed that for other tables that have no association it always contains that entry for itself on the primary key.
So I assumed it was a common entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your schema for the `courses` table the issue would seem to be that you have called your primary key `course_id` rather than the expected `id`. Cake `bake` will interpret this as a foreign key to the `courses` table (*i.e.* itself) so create a `belongsTo` relationship. You should rename the column `id` and stick with [CakePHP's naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html).

Diverging from the naming conventions will almost always cause you more trouble than it's worth. `bake` cannot be expected to know how to build your app correctly if you are not conforming to the standards.

There are few cases where not using the conventions are justified.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks.
I did read the CakePHP conventions docs but I misinterpreted the table ID naming.
Schema changes and baked back all and it's working fine now.